# How generate XML file

Tags: xml, talend

I have a XML file input in TALEND and I want to create a flow for each element, then group by Id.

But the problem is that I have two loop tags so I couldn't generate the same file XML as the input.

Is there any solution to do it?

Comment: Please add a simple example to clarify your question.
You could take a look at tFileInputMSXML or tFileOutputMSXML

Comment: If you can put a sample of your input xml and what you want as output, I can have an idea what you want to explain.